# Views2 Sub-Query Filter

Tags: 6, views

I am trying to recreate the following query in Drupal 6 Views2...

```
SELECT m.PartnerID, m.PartnerName, mc.Description
FROM member AS m 
     LEFT JOIN membercategory AS mc ON m.PartnerID = mc.PartnerID 
WHERE mc.DirectoryID = %d 
  AND mc.CategoryID = (
         SELECT m_xref.CategoryID 
         FROM memeber_membercategory_xref AS m_xref 
         WHERE m_xref.WebCategoryName = '%s'
      )
```

I have been able to create the LEFT JOIN by creating an implicit join on my hook_views_data.
**I am currently stuck on how to create the sub-query on mc.CategoryID in the WHERE clause. Any suggestions?**

Would the only option to be a custom handler for the filter? Or is there a way to get the relationship defined?

My current hook_views_data...

```
function member_display_views_data(){
    $data = array();

    /****
     * Members Table 
     ***/
    $data['member']['table']['group'] = t('Member Data');
    $data['member']['table']['base'] = array(
        'field' => 'PartnerID',
        'title' => t('Members'),
        'help' => t("Member data."),
    );

    $data['member']['PartnerID'] = array(
        'title' => t('Partner ID'),
        'help' => t('The Partner ID.'),
        'field' => array(
            'handler' => 'views_handler_field_numeric',
        ),
        'argument' => array(
            'handler' => 'views_handler_argument_numeric',
        ),
        'filter' => array(
            'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_numeric',
        ),
        'sort' => array(
            'handler' => 'views_handler_sort',
        ),
    );

    $data['member']['PartnerName'] = array(
        'title' => t('Partner Name'),
        'help' => t('The Partner Name.'),
        'field' => array(
            'handler' => 'views_handler_field',
        ),
        'argument' => array(
            'handler' => 'views_handler_argument_string',
        ),
        'filter' => array(
            'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_string',
        ),
        'sort' => array(
            'handler' => 'views_handler_sort_string',
        ),
    );

    $data['member']['Alias'] = array(
        'title' => t('Alias'),
        'help' => t('The alias to identifiy the record.'),
        'field' => array(
            'handler' => 'views_handler_field',
        ),
        'argument' => array(
            'handler' => 'views_handler_argument_string',
        ),
        'filter' => array(
            'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_string',
        ),
        'sort' => array(
            'handler' => 'views_handler_sort_string',
        ),
    );

    /****
     * MemberCategory Table
     ***/
    $data['membercategory']['table']['group'] = t('Member Category Data');
    $data['membercategory']['table']['base'] = array(
        'field' => 'PartnerID',
        'title' => t('Member Category'),
        'help' => t("Member Category data."),
    );
    $data['membercategory']['table']['join'] = array(
        'member' => array(
            'left_field' => 'PartnerID',
            'field' => 'PartnerID',
        ),
    );

    $data['membercategory']['PartnerID'] = array(
        'title' => t('Partner ID'), 
        'help' => t('The Partner ID.'),
        'relationship' => array(
            'base' => 'member', 
            'field' => 'PartnerID', 
            'handler' => 'views_handler_relationship',
        ),
    );
    $data['membercategory']['DirectoryID'] = array(
        'title' => t('Directory ID'),
        'help' => t('The Directory ID.'),
        'field' => array(
            'handler' => 'views_handler_field_numeric',
        ),
        'argument' => array(
            'handler' => 'views_handler_argument_numeric',
        ),
        'filter' => array(
            'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_numeric',
        ),
        'sort' => array(
            'handler' => 'views_handler_sort',
        ),
    );
    $data['membercategory']['CategoryID'] = array(
        'title' => t('Category ID'),
        'help' => t('The Category ID.'),
        'field' => array(
            'handler' => 'views_handler_field_numeric',
        ),
        'argument' => array(
            'handler' => 'views_handler_argument_numeric',
        ),
        'filter' => array(
            'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_numeric',
        ),
        'sort' => array(
            'handler' => 'views_handler_sort',
        ),
    );
    $data['membercategory']['Description'] = array(
        'title' => t('Description'),
        'help' => t('The Partner Description.'),
        'field' => array(
            'handler' => 'views_handler_field',
        ),
        'filter' => array(
            'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_string',
        ),
    );

    /****
     * memeber_membercategory_xref Table
     ***/
    $data['memeber_membercategory_xref']['table']['group'] = t('Member Category xRef');
    $data['memeber_membercategory_xref']['table']['base'] = array(
        'field' => 'PartnerID',
        'title' => t('Member Category xRef'),
        'help' => t("Member Category Cross Reference data."),
    );
    $data['memeber_membercategory_xref']['table']['join'] = array(
        'membercategory' => array(
            'left_field' => 'CategoryID',
            'field' => 'CategoryID',
        ),
    );

    $data['memeber_membercategory_xref']['CategoryID'] = array(
        'title' => t('Category ID'), 
        'help' => t('Partner Category ID.'),
        'relationship' => array(
            'base' => 'membercategory', 
            'field' => 'CategoryID', 
            'handler' => 'views_handler_relationship',
        ),
    );
    $data['memeber_membercategory_xref']['WebCategoryName'] = array(
        'title' => t('Partner Category Name'),
        'help' => t('The Partner Category Name.'),
        'field' => array(
            'handler' => 'views_handler_field',
        ),
        'argument' => array(
            'handler' => 'views_handler_argument_string',
        ),
        'filter' => array(
            'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_string',
        ),
        'sort' => array(
            'handler' => 'views_handler_sort_string',
        ),
    );

    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that using the [Table Wizard](http://drupal.org/project/tw) module allows Drupal Views to load a database view. After install of Table Wizard, go to /admin/content/tw and select your database view from the list of tables to add to Table Wizard. The Drupal view type is prepended with 'Database table'.